# Can lmer be used for a longitudinal study?

Tags: lme4-nlme, panel-data

I have a longitudinal dataset where kids at 4,5, and 6 years of age came to lab and were trained with different pictures. We collected reaction times (DV) before and after the training (pre_post). Does the following model look okay?

```
model<-lmer(RT~pre_post*pictures*Age+ (1+Age|participant),data=data,REML=F)
```

Or is there other ways to handle longitudinal datasets in lmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to parameterize it would be to fit a longitudinal ANCOVA with post-test RT as the outcome, and pre-test as a time-varying predictor. If your main interest is in tracking post-test RT as a function of age, this gives you a direct measure of the age effect at post test, while controlling for the pretest. This seems more straightforward and should be a more reliable way to produce estimates.

See this for more: http://hbiostat.org/bbr/md/change.html#whats-wrong-with-change-in-general

This approach will require you to change the structure of your dataset, unfortunately. The way you have it now, your DV is (both pre and post) RT, and then you've got the pre_post factor to tell the difference between pre and post. To run the revised model, you'd need your DV to be POST RTs only, and add a column for PRE RT. So in pseudo code:

`newmod <- lmer(PostRT ~ PRE_RT + pictures*Age + (1+Age|participant), data=data, REML=F)`

However, if, as in your comment, you would like to test the interaction (moderation, not mediation) between age and the RT difference, you'd need to keep it the way you have it.

Finally, do you think that the picture effect is fixed or random? Is your view that the pictures (stimuli) are a random sample from a population of possible pictures? If so, you might change your version so pictures represent a random effect:

`model<-lmer(RT ~ pre_post*Age + (1+Age|participant) + (1|pictures), data=data, REML=F)`

Also, for reference this is a great article from psycholinguistics that discusses general approaches to your situation: https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0749596X07001398

Comment: Wow, I never thought about using pre_test as a predictor. This actually makes a lot of sense. I'll work on this now. Thanks for all the useful suggestions.

Comment: No problem. And it's your choice as to whether you do the pre-post change model or the ANCOVA. I've gone back and forth myself

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is a classic textbook use case linear mixed models for repeated measures/longitudinal datasets.
The random-effects portion of your parameterization allows for varying intercepts and age slopes which makes sense.

The variable `pre_post` variable isn`t very clear to me. It is common to have a pre-test/procedure measurement, which makes sense, but the "post" part seems like a data leakage.

I wouldn't fit all interactions between main effects as well. I would only keep the ones important for the research to measure and test for the ones that appear to exist in the exploratory/inspective/descriptive part of the analysis.

Comment: Oh, perfect! That was going to be my next question. So, they did the exact same test after the training. We hypothesized that their RTs would be faster after training (post) compared to before training (pre). We also hypothesized that this could be mediated by their development (age).